# FDT5 doesn't like s:RemoteObject

Tags: fdt

Even the simplest Flex project using the normal s:RemoteObject syntax moans it can't resolve RemoteObject. The rpc.swc is correctly listed in the build options.
You can replicate this by creating a new Flex project and add

```
    <s:RemoteObject>
    </s:RemoteObject>
```

in the fx:Declarations block.

FDT5 on Linux, Eclipse 3.5 though it also happens on my licenced FDT3.5. Works fine in Flex Builder.

Screen shot : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/568024/fdt5-remoteobject.png

Comment: Hey Tom. Are you getting warnings just in the Editor, the compiler or both? Can you provide a screenshot or code sample? Here is me trying to recreate what you're describing. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/154189/web/stackexchange/remote_obj.png

Comment: thanks for the help Alan. Compiles OK on command line. Shot attached.